# ¿Cómo obtengo información de una tabla que no exista en otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, distinct

Tengo dos tablas, la primera incluye los productos que un vendedor puede vender (*vendedor_x_producto*), la segunda es una tabla de *ventas*, que contiene las ventas realizadas por cada vendedor y donde se indica que fue lo que vendió.

Requiero realizar una consulta SQL para **obtener** aquellos productos que **NO** están asignados a un vendedor y que **tampoco** vendió ese mismo vendedor, pero que además sean productos **disponibles**.

*Por ejemplo, el vendedor Juan:*

- Tiene asignados los productos: Fresa y Naranja
- Y vendió los productos: Piña y Fresa
- Por lo tanto, mi resultado para esta consulta sería: **Manzana**, que es el único producto que no tiene asignado, que no vendió y que además está disponible.

*Un segundo ejemplo, el vendedor Luis:*

- No tiene asignados productos.
- Tampoco realizó ventas.
- Por lo tanto, mi resultado para esta consulta serían todos los productos disponibles: **Piña, Fresa, Manzana**.

*Último ejemplo, la vendedora Rosa:*

- Tiene asignados los productos: Uva y Piña.
- Y vendió los productos: Manzana y Piña.
- Por lo tanto, mi resultado para esta consulta sería: **Fresa**, que es el único producto no asignado, que no vendió y que está disponible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Agradezco las ideas que puedan proporcionarme!

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado

Comment: Buen formato, bien escrita, ordenada... Pero Japv tiene razón. No pusiste lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver... si tuvieses una tabla de productos podrías hacer algo del estilo:

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE 
    productos.id_producto NOT IN (SELECT  id_producto FROM ventas WHERE id_vendedor = X) 
    AND productos.id_producto NOT IN (SELECT  id_producto FROM vendedor_x_producto WHERE id_vendedor = X)
```

Como no la tienes podrías generarla a partir de tus dos tablas:

```
(SELECT id_producto, producto FROM ventas UNION DISTINCT SELECT id_producto, producto FROM vendedor_x_producto ) AS productos
```

Pero no va a funcionar con tus datos de ejemplo, ya que parece que no hay coherencia con los campos id_producto y producto de las dos tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `UNION` y `LEFT JOIN`

Podría resultar en algo así

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT vendedor FROM vendedor_x_producto
UNION
SELECT vendedor FROM ventas) AS vendedores
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT producto FROM vendedor_x_producto WHERE disponible
UNION
SELECT producto FROM ventas) AS Productos) todos 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT vendedor, producto FROM vendedor_x_producto WHERE disponible
UNION
SELECT vendedor, producto FROM ventas) vendedor_productos ON todos.vendedor = vendedor_productos.vendedor AND todos.producto =  vendedor_productos.producto
WHERE vendedor_productos.vendedor IS NULL AND vendedor_productos.producto IS NULL;
```

Usando las Union para obtener las listas completas de productos y vendedores, también obtener todas las posibilidades entre vendedores-productos y luego la RightJoin para poder sacar las combinaciones no existentes en las tablas actuales.

*La eficiencia no forma parte de los requisitos en esta posible respuesta a tu problema*

Answer (score 0):

Creo que faltan dos tablas más en el ejemplo para lo que quieres. La primera tabla que te falta es la tabla 'producto'. Y la segunda tabla que te falta es la de 'vendedor'.
En el segundo caso, el de Luis, se ve claro por qué te faltarían dos tablas. Si este no tiene asignados productos, y no tiene ventas, y quieres mostrar todos los productos, estos se sacarán de la tabla producto y el vendedor Luis estará en la tabla vendedor.

En resumen, hay que hacer una subconsulta. Esta subconsulta traerá la relación de las cuatro tablas mediante un `left join` que lo que hace es traer la relacion si la hay, pero si no la hubiera obtiene los registros de la tabla de la izquierda. Y luego mediante un select con `not in` nos traemos todos los productos que no estén en la subconsulta anterior.

Por lo tanto creo que tu consulta sería algo así:

```
SELECT prod.producto FROM producto prod
WHERE prdo.producto NOT IN (
  SELECT prod.producto FROM producto prod
  LEFT JOIN vendedor_x_producto vxp ON vxp.producto = prod.producto
  LEFT JOIN ventas vent ON vent.vendedor = vxp.vendedor
  LEFT JOIN vendedor vend ON vend.vendedor = vxp.vendedor
  WHERE vend.vendedor = "nombreVendedor" and vxp.disponible = true
)
```